DuckDB support for Postgres function WITH ORDINALITY
Currently i'm using DuckDB to execute the following Postgres query containing WITH ORDINALITY function on a polars dataframe:
with suffixes as (
select ordrnbr,(nr-1)/2 N
  ,max(case when nr%2=1 then elem end) Nkey
  ,cast(max(case when nr%2=0 then elem end) as int) Nval
from test t
left join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t.description, '@'))
                    WITH ORDINALITY AS a(elem, nr) ON true
group by ordrnbr,(nr-1)/2
)

select concat(t.ordrnbr,'-',row_number()over(partition by t.ordrnbr order by s.N))ordrnbr
  , vehiclename,    description,    id, totprice
  ,coalesce(s.Nval,totprice) ind_price
from test t
left join suffixes s on s.ordrnbr=t.ordrnbr
where s.Nval>=10000 or (s.Nval is null and totPrice>=10000)

When i tried executing this query, Duck DB throws an error

exception:duckdb.duckdb.NotImplementedException: Not implemented
Error: WITH ORDINALITY not implemented

Is there any other way that we could acheive this using DuckDB?
Any help would be appreciated please.

DuckDB solution:
You can use generate_subscripts() to generate indexes along the dimension of the array.
To simplify your example a bit, let's say you want to split hello@world
select
    unnest(a.data) as v, generate_subscripts(a.data, 1) as i
from values (
    string_to_array('hello@world', '@')
) as a(data)

┌─────────┬───────┐
│    v    │   i   │
│ varchar │ int64 │
├─────────┼───────┤
│ hello   │     1 │
│ world   │     2 │
└─────────┴───────┘

Your query might become something like:
with nr as (
    select
        t.ordrnbr,
        unnest(v.description) as elem,
        generate_subscripts(v.description, 1) as nr
    from test t,
        values (string_to_array(t.description, '@')) as v(description)
), suffixes as (
    select
        t.ordrnbr,
        (t.nr - 1) / 2 as N,
        max(case when t.nr % 2 = 1 then t.elem end) as Nkey,
        cast(max(case when t.nr % 2 = 0 then t.elem end) as int) as Nval
    from nr as t
    group by
        ordrnbr,
        (t.nr - 1) / 2
)
select
    concat(t.ordrnbr, '-', row_number() over(partition by t.ordrnbr order by s.N)) as ordrnbr,
    t.vehiclename,
    t.description,
    t.id,
    t.totprice,
    coalesce(s.Nval, t.totprice) as ind_price
from test t
    left join suffixes s on s.ordrnbr = t.ordrnbr
where
    s.Nval>=10000 or (s.Nval is null and totPrice >= 10000)

Personally I'd probably go with filtering the array first and avoiding groupby + join. You can see example of this approach below, but in pure polars solution
Polars solution

.str.split() to split description into list.
.list.gather_every() to get all even elements of the list.
.list.eval(), element() and .filter() to filter elements >= 10000
int_ranges() to create index for list elements (so gives you WITH ORDINALITY results after next operation).
.list.explode() to convert list into rows.

(
    test.with_columns(
        pl.col.description
        .str.split('@')
        .list.gather_every(2, 1)
        .list.eval(
            pl.element().filter(
                pl.element().cast(pl.Float64) >= 10000
            )
        ).alias('ind_price')
    )
    .filter(
        (pl.col.ind_price.list.len() > 0) | (pl.col.totprice >= 10000)
    )
    .with_columns(N = pl.int_ranges(pl.col.ind_price.list.len()))
    .explode('ind_price', 'N')
    .with_columns(
        pl.concat_str(pl.col.ordrnbr, pl.lit('-'), pl.col.N.fill_null(0) + 1),
        pl.col.ind_price.cast(pl.Float64).fill_null(pl.col.totprice)
    )
    .drop('N')
)


I have a table here https://dbfiddle.uk/YlaNkbJN which will be read as polars dataframe. Here if the description does not contain delimiter i.e., @ then  the corresponding totprice column should be considered and if it is less than 10000 then it needs to be filtered out otherwise the ordrnbr should be prefixed with -1,-2,-3 respectively. I tried the above polars way and for hubseqnbr it comes with null and txnamt also comes as null and similarly for other two columns. I'm casting as pl.Float64 as the delimiter values could contain decimal values. Can you please help me on this?

@BalajiVenkatachalam I've updated the answer

For Duck Db solution, all we need to do is replace (t.nr - 1) / 2 with (t.nr - 1) // 2 as the division operator in duckdb is represented as //. Thanks for the Polars solution.
